# Is there an ansible strategy that takes host groups into account?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

We use an inventory file and ansible. We have many micro services and sometimes we have different instances for internal and external use. AFAIK, the builtin ansible strategies (free, host_pinned, serial) ignore the groups. Is there a strategy that works like `host_pinned` but on a per group basis?

Example inventory:

```
[my-service-external]
my-external-hosts[01:57].example.com

[my-service-internal]
my-internal-hosts[1:3].example.com

[my-service:children]
my-service-external
my-service-internal
```

Example playbook.yml:

```
---
- name: ping
  hosts: my-service
  strategy: host_pinned
  serial:
    - 1
    - "30%"
  tasks:
    - name: ping
      ansible.builtin.ping:
```

If this playbook would do something that would actually impact the service, like restarting some application server, all internal hosts would go down at pretty much the same time and possibly cause an outage.

Comment: The existing strategy plugin list is pretty sparse, but [it is a plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/plugins/strategy.html) and thus is subject to you making -- or perhaps finding one -- which behaves like you want

Comment: @mdaniel I know that those are plugins but I was wondering if there already is one...

Comment: if you're using a serial of "1", how would they all go down ? if the service restart fails on the first, ansible will not progress to the next.

Comment: @G_G It uses 1 in the first round (so it restarts 1 host), afterwards it restarts 30% of hosts until there are no more hosts left
If I'd use a serial of 1 the whole time, deployments would take all day because we have services with a hundred hosts or so...

Comment: @armin fair enough. however, even with 30% per batch after the first one, at most you'll be left with 30% down being a failed restart stops the execution, no ?

Comment: @G_G Looking at my example, 30% would restart 18 hosts at once, meaning that it would all 3 hosts in the internal group + 15 hosts from the external group. Meaning all internal hosts would go down.